# Does anyone have any pproximate idea what it would cost to get a FIX and OUCH connection from NASDAQ

Tags: market-data, market-microstructure, feed

I would like to know how much the exchange fees would be to connect and place orders directly with NASDAQ using one of their third party suppliers or directly. I took a look at the pricing page but it is not very clear what are the items I would have to subscribe for. I would guess I need colocation to be directly connected to the NADAQ market, I would also need an extranet connection though iam not sure if the colocation price includes this. I would also need a FIX feed and an OUCH to place orders. Is there any other items I should include and how much would a setup like this cost ? I am not looking for exact numbers , but if someone is using a setup like this, how much would it cost approximately ?

Comment: This kind of thing is highly variable and subject to a lot of negotiation and details, but basic connections you should be able to get for 2500 per month plus about 700 for an execution port. I don't know about direct rack space, but if you work with a service provider like Pico you should be able to get 1U or 2U for under 1000 per month. These numbers are also highly subject to future change.

Comment: @deftfyodor 2500 is for both the datafeed and the order feed or only the data feed ? When you say execution port can it be shared for the datafeed ? If not then do I need 2 data ports

Comment: 2500 is just for the wire going to the exchange, no data would be included in that. The 700 would cover order entry capabilities. Market data is extra and pricing depends a lot on what you need, but it's pretty easy to get a quote from them directly if you just send them an email.